# Get Manufacturer Name from Setup

Tags: .net, installation, app-data

In .NET, when creating a setup project the application files are stored in a path similar to this:

`C:\Program Files\[Manufacturer]\[Product Name]`

I am generating a folder inside of the common application data so I can read/write on Win 7 without admin privileges, so I also generated a folder at this path:

`C:\ProgramData\[Manufacturer]\[Product Name]`

What's the best way to get this path in code so I can read/write to this folder?

I could just put the manufacturer name in a constant string and keep it in sync. Or I could add it to the assembly manifest of one of the projects. Or I could try to save it out to file during the setup?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you actually having with this?

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the path to the application data.

Comment: If I use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) I can get the OS specific path to C:\ProgramData or the like, but I would rather not hardcode the manufacturer name.

Comment: How are you getting the manufacturer name?

Comment: You specify it as a property of the setup project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I would do anything in setup other than create the directory.  Let the application manage getting to the directory at runtime.

I would save your Manufacturer and Product Name in a config file or a hard coded constant in your code. You could also do some kind of reflection to look it up from the assembly, but this is overkill in my mind.

For the `ProgramData` directory, use the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` environment variable to get the location. That way it would work across all versions of windows.

Then concatenate the environment variable and manufacturer / product name to build the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to look into the [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.context.aspx) of the installer instance, to store the path and later find it within the [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installcontext.parameters.aspx).

You will need to set the value [`CustomActionData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the appropriate path (such as `/TargetDir="[TARGETDIR]"`, or any other such variables that are available and desired.)

Then, in code, and as required, grab the path from the `Parameters` property of the the `Context`, as mentioned above:

```
var path Context.Parameters.Item("TargetDir")
```

Comment: This would work inside of a custom installer action, but I need to get at this data from the installed application itself.

Comment: @Josh G: Then in that case, either hard-code them somewhere, or do some string manipulation based on physical location of the executing assembly to get the data you need, along with any other parts you may require such as expanding environment variables. But please update your question, as right now it implies you wish to do this at installation, via the installer.